# Make PDF editable in Java

Tags: java, pdf

I have a PDF which is nothing but some form , for example, i have employeesheet as PDF form which is not editable.

i want to make this editable using any Java PDF api..

it would highly appreciated if you give me an solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Look into Apache PDFBox.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout http://itextpdf.com/

Answer (score 0):

iText can do this - but why would you want to do this from code?  Just create the form in Acrobat or open office and be done with it.  If you are trying to populate the form from a database or something, then iText would definitely be the tool for you, but adding and manipulating form elements is best done with a GUI tool.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the PDF actually contains form elements. Otherwise you can do very limited editing.